# how to make Jenkins wait until artifacts are completed?

Tags: jenkins

**Situation :**

Some tests are executed directly on the slave. However they may make the task crash (blue screen).

**Problem :**

The test fails after a while, the slave shows a blue screen. Then Jenkins master will try to perform post build task, but he won't be able to since the slave is down. In the post build task, it waits to create artifacts, then give up after a while.

I would need Jenkins to keep trying building the artifacts until the slave is rebooted and Jenkins is able to finish building the artifacts or either we manually kill the build.

Is there a way to do this? Haven't found anything so far.

Comment: What tests? What is Jenkins doing you want it to keep trying until ...? Please consider considering [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GeroldBroser I updated my question. It should be more clear now.

Comment: Is this valid test behaviour to crash the slave machine? This sounds really strange. And again: What tests do you perform? I guess unit tests, since you write "keep trying building the artifacts", but guessing is not enough for a decent answer.

Comment: 1-) Yes it is a normal behaviour, we are testing drivers and they are in early development stages. 2-) The tests are Nunit tests that uses functions from the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. If a job is executed on a slave it is executed there completely. Once the job is started there the master merely receives and displays the console output and the final result status. So, your "Then Jenkins master will try to perform post build task" is not how it works.

And, please, answer the questions asked in the comments if you want to get a decent answer.